# How to apply loss penalty to specific layers in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a neural network which essentially has 2 parts A and B, I have defined a custom loss function say `l = l1(A) + l2(A, B)`. Only the layers of part A are responsible for loss `l1`, so during backpropagation I want to apply the penalty of `l1` to only those layers and `l2` is from the whole network so I want to apply the penalty of `l2` to all the layers. How can this be achieved in Keras?

I have been using a weighted sum of the losses up until now, but it is not what I have in mind, here is some code from my training loop:

```py
net_loss = lambda_1 * l1 + lambda_2 * l2
gradients = tape.gradient(net_loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

I have not found a way to do partial gradient calculation and application, please help me with this.

Comment: why don't you add penalization to the layers directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to update weights of different layers with respect to different loss functions, you can separate `model.trainable_variables` into different groups when calculating gradients and doing the weight updates.

Like this (minimal example):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

preprocess = lambda x, y: (x, tf.one_hot(y, 3))

ds = tfds.load('iris', split='train', as_supervised=True).map(preprocess)

train = ds.batch(4)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name='pen1'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name='pen2'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='pen1b')
])

model.build(input_shape=(None, 4))

loss_fn1 = tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
loss_fn2 = tf.losses.BinaryFocalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

all_variables = model.trainable_variables

variables1 = list(filter(lambda x: x.name.startswith('pen1'), all_variables))
variables2 = list(filter(lambda x: x.name.startswith('pen2'), all_variables))

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()
optimizer.build(variables1 + variables2)

verbose = "Epoch {:2d} Loss1: {:.3f}  Loss2: {:.3f}"

for epoch in range(1, 5 + 1):
    train_loss1 = tf.metrics.Mean()
    train_loss2 = tf.metrics.Mean()

    for x, y in train:
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            out = model(x, training=True)
            loss1 = loss_fn1(out, y)
            loss2 = loss_fn2(out, y)

        grads1 = tape.gradient(loss1, variables1)
        grads2 = tape.gradient(loss2, variables2)

        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, variables1))
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, variables2))

        train_loss1.update_state(loss1)
        train_loss2.update_state(loss2)

    print(verbose.format(epoch, train_loss1.result(), train_loss2.result()))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch, I did jerry rig something like this but was unsure if it was correct since I got errors. That persistent = True did the trick. Also can you please tell what is the appropriate place to call delete tape?

Comment: I'm not sure but there's information [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#reset)